# Async taking 15x longer than sync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm comparing the performance when taking away `await` keyword from my method, and it's giving me over 15x better performance.

The following method performs much better:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AwaitResponse(HttpRequest proxy)
{
    foreach (var header in proxy.Request.Headers)
    {
        Client.Instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy.Request).Result;
    return response;
}
```

**than this one:**

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AwaitResponse(HttpRequest proxy)
{
    foreach (var header in proxy.Request.Headers)
    {
        Client.Instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy.Request);
    return await response;
}
```

Notice How I am calling **.Result** in the first version of the method.

**Why is this happening? Why is there such a tremendous performance penalty?**

Please note that `Client` is simply a static instance of `HttpClient`.

Comment: 1. You say "x15 increase", but you didn't specify numbers. Is this 10ms vs 150ms, or 200ms vs. 3000ms? This matters.
2. Are there many other concurrent requests doing similar operations at the same time? `await` relinquishes the thread and has to marshal the context back to where it was when it returns. If there are many requests, your threadpool might be busy.
3. Does adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your `await` change the behavior?

Comment: it goes from 1000 to 12000 ms

Comment: there are no other concurrent requests

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `await`, the execution context of the code is suspended until the async method returns. By default, `await` attempts to restore the new thread to the incoming synchronization context that it originated in. This can sometimes have performance implications, as the CLR needs to wait for the original SynchronizationContext to marshal back.

Generally speaking, unless you have a specific need to return to the same thread context that you left (say, in a client app, to return to the UI thread), it's best to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` and continue on any arbitrary thread.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you do not actually use the response for anything in the snippets there is no need to actually use async/await or to call `.Result`. You can just return the `Task` for the caller to await or call `.Result` at a higher level.

```
private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> AwaitResponse(HttpRequest proxy) {
    foreach (var header in proxy.Request.Headers) {
        Client.Instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }
    return Client.Instance.SendAsync(proxy.Request);
}
```

I would also suggest reviewing

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) from  Stephen Cleary

the issues around not mixing blocking and async code and also about how and when to `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you can

Comment: this is a great point, so you are saying "what is the purpose of using the async/await at all if i have no use for it in my application? rather, have the client do that?"  ??

Comment: No, the keywords async/await are only needed it you needed to hold on to the context for further processing. For example is you needed to do something within the method with the result after calling `SendAsync`,  then `async/await` would be warranted. You however do not need that in this case so there was no need to use `async/await` in this method.

Comment: While you *can* elide the async/await and simply return the inner Task from your own async function, it's not always the best choice. Here's Stephen Cleary, again, on the [pros and cons](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). In short, returning the inner task directly makes your functiuon not show up in the stack trace if there's an exception.